# Django Add Two Numbers

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I am new to Django. I am having a hard time finishing this application. Overall, I am trying to have one form that accepts two different numbers and then adds those numbers together. This is what I have so far, but I know there must be errors somewhere. Also, I do not know what I need to return exactly. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Also, it would be nice to display the output on a new page. I assume I would accomplish this by adding another html file. However, could you please provide how this would be accomplished as well.

forms.py:

```
from django import forms


class InputForm(forms.Form):
     x = forms.IntegerField(label='Enter first number: ')
     y = forms.IntegerField(label='Enter second number: ')
```

views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
from .forms import InputForm

def add(request):
    form = InputForm(request.POST or None)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = InputForm(request.POST or None)
        if form.is_valid():
            cd = form.cleaned_data
            input1 = cd['x']
            input2 = cd['y']
            output = input1 + input2
            return ???
    else:
        form = InputForm()
        return render(request, 'addition/home.html')
```

urls.py:

```
 from django.urls import path
 from . import views

 urlpatterns = [
     path('', views.add, name='addition-home'),
 ]
```

home.html:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html lang="en" dir="ltr">
   <head>
     <meta charset="utf-8">
     <title>Home</title>
   </head>
   <body>
     <form class="addform" method="post">
       {% csrf_token %}
       <input type="number" name="firstnumber" label="Enter first number: ">
       <input type="number" name="secondnumber" label="Enter second number: ">
       <button type="submit" name="sumbit">Submit</button>
     </form>

   </body>
 </html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe try that here:

views.py

```
def add(request):
    context = []
    form = InputForm(request.POST or None)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = InputForm(request.POST or None)
        if form.is_valid():
            cd = form.cleaned_data
            input1 = cd['x']
            input2 = cd['y']
            print(output)
            # You should see the number in your terminal
            context['output'] = output
            # remove return
    else:
        form = InputForm()

return render(request, 'addition/home.html', context)
```

template.html

```
{{ output }}
```